# What is CP? Why is it important?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-go

Pokémon have a statistic called ***CP***. What does it do, and why is it relevant?

Is it a substitute for the nonexistent levels and statistics, or is it something completely different?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

CP is an abbreviation for **C**ombat **P**ower. It is an aggregate statistic that represents how powerful any specific Pokemon is, based on their IVs (Stamina, Attack, and Defense) and their current Level.

It is a safe (general) assumption that a Pokemon with a higher CP will tend to fare better in battle than one with a lower CP. If two Pokemon of the same species, CP, IV, Level, and Moveset were to battle, the fight will likely result in a draw.

CP, however, is not a determination of who wins a battle. There are a number of extra factors that influence battles:

- **Type Advantages**
  Like all previous Pokemon games, [type advantages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VddYK.png) between different Pokemon still take effect. For example, a Water Pokemon will have an advantage over a Fire Pokemon.
  [image: Pokemon Type Advantages]
- **Same Type Attack Bonus**
  If a Pokemon has the same Type as the move being used, a Pokemon will gain a [25% Attack Boost](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L243).
- **IVs**
  Pokemon, like in the main series, have IVs on their core statistics. A high-Defense Pokemon may very well fare very well against a Pokemon with a higher CP, depending on the attacker's IVs.
- **Speed**
  Typically, a Trainer has an inherent edge against a Gym Pokemon because a Trainer can attack faster and with more ferocity.
- **Dodging**
  Trainers may "dodge" attacks from Gym Pokemon, with grants them a specific advantage that may turn the battle into their favor, regardless of IVs.

Two Pokemon with the same CP are not always equal -- they may have different levels and IVs, making them vastly different and useful (or useless) in different cases.

CP can be increased by [powering up](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272610/76693) the Pokémon through the use of Candies, and through evolution. Note, however, that CP will not cause your Pokémon to evolve -- this must be separately triggered.

Pokemon CPs can range from a minimum of 10 to an upper limit determined by their IVs and a Pokemon's Level. A list of Max CPs is available [here](http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-list), for those who are interested.

Comment: Do you know if all pokemon of the same species have the same min/max CP? And you just catch some that have been powered up more?

Comment: How do you know the CP is an aggregate for all these other hidden stats? Is there an official source for that or is this just guesswork? It also contradicts "Two of the same Pokemon of equal CP and equal attacks will do exactly the same amount of damage to each other." because they could have different distribution of these stats, no?

I've found that pokemon can have the same CP but different HP which lends credibility to the "aggregate stat" theory, but doesn't confirm it.

Comment: @user109486 Beta testing and game data mining.

Comment: @KazWolfe Hm ok, do you have a link to a writeup or any extra details? This is the only place where I've seen this theory.

Comment: Just to nitpick. "CP" is not an acronym. Just an abbreviation. :)

Comment: @KazWolfe What is the maximum CP a Pokemon can have ?

Comment: "The higher the CP of a Pokémon, the stronger the Pokémon is and the more damage it can do per attack." If this is the case, then what is the relevance of the regular and power attacks shown for each Pokémon? For instance, if I have a Pokémon with a regular attack of 10 and a power attack of 50, does a higher CP affect these values?

Comment: Does a high cp mean it's stronger than a low cp pokemon? Or the low cp pokemon can be upgraded and match the high cp one? If so, then does this means that both can reach the same max capacity?

Comment: So if I have two Pokemon of the same type and attacks and with the same CP, but one is a 'wonder' and the other is 'not likely to make much headway in battle' when appraised, does it matter which one I use in battle?