# How to tell Max CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm comparing different pokemon of the same type (e.g. comparing pidgeys with each other), to see which ones I want to keep and which to transfer. I want to select based on Max CP -which differs per each pokemon-, but it's a bitch to find what a pokémon's max CP would be.

Even though the bar fill isn't very accurate (not determined per every 1%), if a CP bar is filled to 50%, it's not hard to find out what the max CP of that pokemon is. But otherwise, since there are no round measurement tools in any software I know of, it stays at mere guessing.

Does anyone know of a way to do this effectively?

Comment: `since there are no round measurement tools in any software` - Consider hardware? A protractor is an angle measuring tool.

Comment: Good suggestion. But, wouldn't i need a protractor with the exact same radius to lay it over the bar on my screen?

Comment: No, you just have the measure the change if you upgrade it once

Comment: Sorry but you lost me. I don't understand how that is related to measuring the CP bar to find the max CP value?

Comment: I answered instead.

Comment: Do you want to know the maximum possible for each Pokémon (maxed out to level 40), or the maximum you can power the Pokémon to based on your current trainer level?

Comment: @Tester101 The latter, although the former would be a good alternative. I don't suppose there is a way to know without knowing the current level's max though..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this with a protractor. Originally I thought you'd need to do an upgrade and measure the difference, but I was making it more complicated than it needs to be.

[image]

Thankfully, the bar is exactly half a circle, this makes things a bit easier with a standard protractor. I have assumed that the bar is linear, meaning that if the bar is half full, then the Pokémon is at half of it's max CP.

The bar on this example is `110 / 180` or about 60% full.

You can then work out your estimated max level with this formula:

```
max = CurrentCP / (angle / 180)
```

---

```
Example:
max = 72        / (110 / 180)
max = 72        /  0.61
max = 118
```

---

Based on the other answer, it seems that the max CP *might* change as you level up, so you might need to remeasure.

---

> But again, a physical one would have to have the same radius as the image/app on your screen.

Nope, with a ruler (or any straight edge for that matter), you can use a smaller protractor. Just put the protractor so that it's middle is in the middle of the bar and place your straight edge as indicated by the white line.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! So is this protractor you used for this an online tool?

Comment: For this example I simply took an [existing screenshot](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272639/28193) and put an [image of a protractor](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/battle-for-escape/images/6/65/Protractor.png/revision/latest?cb=20150829212647) on top

Comment: You could do the same thing with lots of screenshots, but in the long run I expect its easier to find/buy a physical protractor

Comment: Ah ok, that'll do for me :). But again, a physical one would have to have the same radius as the image/app on your screen. Sure you could take screenshots and zoom them in to the exact right level, but that's almost undoable. But thanks

Comment: @poepje you know how a protractor works? It doesn't need to have a certain radius at all.

Comment: can this be right? a pidgy with 0 angle has CP 10, so there must be some kind of offset? Could you even observe whether the angle increase is linear on power-ups? Can I know/compute the maximum number of power-ups for a given level and a given pokemon?

Comment: @Micka Indeed, at least with low percentages the bar does not fill correctly at all. If I'm not mistaken, below 15% or so the bar sticks to 0% fill. But I also found that though this answer is technically correct, the max CP values of the pokémon seem to be far greater than this calculation gives us. I found out by calculating, then powering up pokemon to their max (while being the same trainer level).

Comment: @poepje by chance: did you take screenshots after each power up? I've observed that the circle doesnt grow linearly for one rattata

Comment: @Micka, I did make the assumption that the bar is linear, but I could well be wrong! Let us know (or feel free to edit) if you do find an equation that works better

Comment: Didnt find something yet. But yesterday I found the theory about so-called IV stats and calculators for that.

Comment: @Micka I didn't, but I too am under the impression that the bar is not reliable at all.

Comment: @JamesWebster Have you tested this theory to see if it holds true? The curve above a Pokémon shows what level the Pokémon is, in reference to what level it can be powered to for the player's current trainer level.  Also, once the Pokémon is past level 30, the amount of CP gained per power up is less.

Answer (score 4):

Your Max CP of a Pokemon is also based on your level, it will increase if your level goes up. And the same Pokemon could have a different CP max. Some have more potential for growth than others.

So there isn't really a way to accurately determine what the max CP of a pokemon is.

Comment: What I mean, of course, is the current map CP (for whatever level you are)

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the exact maximum CP for each Pokémon, as long as you have all the correct data for that specific Pokémon.

### Individual Values

The first thing you're going to have to figure out, are what the individual values (IV) are for each Pokémon you want to compare. Every Pokémon has 3 hidden IVs, one each for Attack, Defense, and Stamina.  These values range from 0 to 15, and are used to calculate the Pokémon's CP.

You can use online tools such as the [IV Calculator](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator) from [Poké Assistant](https://pokeassistant.com/) to find these values.

### Base Stats

The next thing you'll have to look up, are the base stats for whichever species of Pokémon you're comparing. Each species has a set of base stats, which are also used to calculate CP.

You can find base stats all over the web, [The Silph Road](https://thesilphroad.com/) has a whole list of [Species Stats](https://thesilphroad.com/species-stats)

### Level

To calculate the maximum possible CP, you'll simply use level 40 in your calculations. If you want to know what the maximum CP is for your current trainer level, you'll use your trainer level plus 1.5. For example, if you're level 20, you can only power a Pokémon up to level 21.5.

#### CP Multiplier

To calculate CP, you don't use the level directly, instead you have to look up the CP Multiplier for that level. Luckily, the [CP Multiplier](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/cp-multiplier) can also be found on the web, at sites like [GamePress](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/).

### The Formula

The formula looks like this...

`Max CP = Floor(((BaseAttack + IndividualAttack) * (BaseDefense + IndividualDefense)^0.5 * (BaseStamina + IndividualStamina)^0.5 * CPMultiplier^2) / 10)`

As an example, I'll calculate the maximum CP of a 12/14/15 Pidgey if your trainer level was 20.

`Max CP = Floor(((85 + 12) * (76 + 14)^0.5 * (80 + 15)^0.5 * (0.619399365)^2) / 10)`
`Max CP = Floor((97 * 9.4868329805051379959966806332982 * 9.7467943448089639068384131998996 * 0.383655573362403225) / 10)`
`Max CP = Floor((3441.0921526345817698060490793408) / 10)`
`Max CP = Floor(344.10921526345817698060490793408)`
`Max CP = 344`

You can also easily calulate the absolute maximum CP, by simply using the CP Multiplier for level 40.

`Max CP = Floor(((85 + 12) * (76 + 14)^0.5 * (80 + 15)^0.5 * (0.79030001)^2) / 10)`
`Max CP = Floor((97 * 9.4868329805051379959966806332982 * 9.7467943448089639068384131998996 * 0.6245741058060001) / 10)`
`Max CP = Floor((5601.9440442159961329825324916023) / 10)`
`Max CP = Floor(560.19440442159961329825324916023)`
`Max CP = 560`

Answer (score 3):

Maximum cp level of your Pokémon changes as you level up according to an algorithm. Yes, you can measure this with a protractor, but to truly understand the math behind it, you need to look at the data of the system. I would also like to add that it is yet a bit unclear about whether or not the size xs or xl affect this. I do not believe it currently does, but algorithms can change with updates ;)

Based on the data from what someone wrote about max trainer level in another forum, click this link to see the algorithm for max cp increases as you're leveling up. Here is the link to the datamining:

https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884#file-pokemon-go-data-dump-txt-L618

Also-- there's a lot of other useful info in that data, so enjoy ;)

Source article:

"According to this article the maximum trainer Level is 40. They found the information with datamining, there is no official statement about this.

Two more sources (thx to Kaz Wolfe): source1 source2

You need 5 million experience points to reach from level 39 to 40.

Afaik at the moment (20.07) the highest level players reached is level 30 and they need 500k xp for level 31

Comment: Aside from the fact that I have no clue how to read these numbers or what they represent, Pokemon Go is not open-source and therefore it's unlikely that this is a code extraction from the actual game. Unless this KazWolfe hacked the game.

Comment: The code has been datamined :P

Comment: rumours say there are hidden stats like attack, defense and speed. would be logical that height and weight increase attack/def but lower speed? so maybe there is some funny trade-off mechanics :) but just a guess .

Answer (score 1):

To calculate if I am going to keep an Pokemon and train it for gym battles, I look at the skills of the pokemon (do they have the skillset I would like), and at the appraise from the gym leader. That will give a good indication if the pokemon can also achieve a good CP for battle.

But there are also websites where you can calculate how good your pokemon is against other pokemon of the same spiecies.

For example my Ninetailes: [Ninetailes](https://pokemon.gameinfo.io/en/tools/iv-calculator#WzM4LFtbMTQxNiwxMDEsMzUwMF1dLDAsMixbMSwxLCJhdHQiLFtdXSwwXQ==) 
Link to the website: [Link](https://pokemon.gameinfo.io/en/tools/iv-calculator)