# Is the max CP of a hatched Chansey affected by the trainer level you were when you hatched it?

Tags: pokemon-go

I hatched a 90-IV Chansey seven months ago. My trainer level then was 10 (or maybe less?). Does hatching him at such a low trainer level affect the maximum CP? I hatched an 87-IV Chansey last month (trainer level 29).

Would the Chansey I hatched at level 29 have a higher max CP then the one I hatched at trainer level 10?

Comment: let's put it this way; *if* the IVs were 100% identical, the only difference between the lvl 10 hatch and the lvl 29 hatch would be the stardust&candy investment necessary for it to reach max level/cp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pokémon that you hatch inside an egg is determined at the moment you receive the egg.  Nothing after that can affect the Pokémon that is in there.  CP, IVs, moves, everything is set.  (See [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uo5yo/legacy_moveset_in_newly_hatched_egg/) for example to prove that even moveset is predetermined.)

As such, the trainer level that you were at when you hatched the egg is irrelevant.  Only the trainer level you were at when you *received* the egg is relevant.  So if you spin a 10km egg at level 2, and then wait until you're level 20 to hatch it, it's still max level 2.

Insomuch as maximum CP is determined, even that is irrelevant; IVs are the sole determiner of maximum eventual CP.  This is discussed [in this question/answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276169/how-to-tell-max-cp) for example, particularly in the second answer.

Also note that the (very old) Attack bug (where attack was directly proportional to pokedex #) did *not* affect eggs, so that's not related to the possible difference.

Answer (score 3):

In short, **no.** Maximum CP is completely independent of your trainer level.

The only way the CP of a Pokémon would be affected by your trainer level at the time you hatched it is that you couldn't hatch a Chansey at as high of a level from an egg you *received at trainer level 10* than one you hatched after receiving at trainer level 29. This is because the stats of a Pokémon are determined when the egg is received, *not* when it is hatched. **However, maximum CP has nothing to do with trainer level -- this is determined solely by IVs.**

Thus, your 90% Chansey will have a higher maximum CP than your 87% Chansey, but, as mentioned in the comments, the Stardust and Candy cost to bring it to the same level as the Chansey hatched when you were level 29 will be enormous for what is likely a very small difference in CP, seeing as their IVs are both very high. Considering the rarity of Chansey, you may be better off just focusing on your 87% Chansey rather than the 90%, as their maximum CPs will be very close together.